# Best way to implement Timer in Android?

Tags: android, timer, stopwatch, chronometer

I doing some math game, and I have 25 question for user to answer. So, I want to mesaure how much time that user needed for solving that?

So I need something like Timer, stopwatch with ability to pause time when user click on Back button.

I saw few implementations with Chronometer, is that good for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are simply looking to figure out how long the user took you don't even need to use a special object honestly.

Just make a long variable and store the startTime from `System.getCurrentTimeInMillis();`

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
//do problems here
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long totalTime = endTime - startTime;

Log.i("TAG", "It took "+ totalTime / 1000 + " seconds to complete the problems");
```

To do pausing you'll need a long that tracks how long it was paused and subtract that also from the totalTime.

Comment: long pausedTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); long finalTotalTime = endTime - pausedTime; That should work?

Comment: not exactly like that you'll need a startPause and stopPause that you subtract to get pausedTime. But you have the right idea, just play with it a bit and you'll get it =)